# Is it possible to add code to Terraform

Tags: landscape, terraform

Lets say I have two different landscapes AWS and Google Cloud (Only an example, could be any infrastructure).
Both of them have many variety resources, variables etc. Probably the usage and connection will be also different.

I would like to use both of them in same Terraform script, is it even possible? or every landscape needs it's own script?

Can I maybe add some code (if yes which language is supported?) to identify the landscape and run the relevant resources/providers etc.?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Terraform in a cloud agnostic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42789247/how-to-use-terraform-in-a-cloud-agnostic-way)

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple providers in your provider.tf file. I have not tried it across cloud providers but here is the syntax to try.

```
variable "aws_profile" {}

variable "region" {}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "west"
  profile                 = "${var.aws_profile}"
  region                  = "${var.region}"
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
}

provider "google" {
  alias  = "central"
  credentials = "${file("account.json")}"
  project     = "my-gce-project"
  region      = "us-central1"
}
```

Then you can specify the provider for that resource.

```
# West coast region
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "west"
  region = "us-west-2"
}
```

> If a provider isn't specified, then the default provider configuration is used (the provider configuration with no alias set). The value of the provider field is TYPE.ALIAS, such as "aws.west" above.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html

Edit: terraform load order does not matter.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/load.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.
Anyway I meant more like, if I split my script into two files like aws.tf and google.tf something like that and in main.tf (or any other file) I'm specifying which one to run wether aws.tf or google.tf.

Comment: I have added the link to the load order for files. Terraform will load all files in the directory that have .tf or .ksom extension