# How do I convert a terraform file to provision/create VMs in vSphere instead of GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, vmware, vsphere

After going through the below URL, I am able to create/destroy a sample VM on vSphere

[VMware vSphere Provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/vsphere/index.html)

## Contents of different files:

### `provider.tf`

```
provider "vsphere" {
  user           = "${var.vsphere_user}"
  password       = "${var.vsphere_password}"
  vsphere_server = "${var.vsphere_server}"

  # If you have a self-signed cert
  allow_unverified_ssl = true
}

data "vsphere_datacenter" "dc" {
  name = "XYZ400"
}

data "vsphere_datastore" "datastore" {
  name          = "datastore1"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

data "vsphere_resource_pool" "pool" {
  name          = "Pool1"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

data "vsphere_network" "network" {
  name          = "Network1"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vmtest" {
  name             = "terraform-test"
  resource_pool_id = "${data.vsphere_resource_pool.pool.id}"
  datastore_id     = "${data.vsphere_datastore.datastore.id}"

  num_cpus = 2
  memory   = 1024
  guest_id = "other3xLinux64Guest"
  wait_for_guest_net_timeout = 0

  network_interface {
    network_id = "${data.vsphere_network.network.id}"
  }

  disk {
    label = "disk0"
    size  = 20
  }
}
```

### `variables.tf`

```
variable "vsphere_user" {
  description = "vSphere user name"
  default = "username"
}

variable "vsphere_password" {
  description = "vSphere password"
  default = "password"
}

variable "vsphere_server" {
  description = "vCenter server FQDN or IP"
  default = "vCenterURL"
}
```

### `test.tf`

```
data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template" {
  name = "CENTOS7_Template"
  datacenter_id = "${data.vsphere_datacenter.dc.id}"
}
```

Commands used

- `terraform init`
- `terraform validate`
- `terraform plan`
- `terraform apply`
- `terraform destroy`

My next need is to convert existing terraform files **provisioning GCP VMs** to ones in **VMware vSphere cloud environment**. If anybody has an pointers please share.

Comment: There isn't an easy answer to this. You'll need to manually rewrite your Terraform to use VSphere instead of GCP and this will be entirely down to what you've done so far in GCP.

Comment: Thanks @ydaetskcoR. Do you know if there is list of resources which corresponds GCP and vSphere. 

For ex:
`google_compute_address` --> `vsphere_virtual_machine`

Comment: Those are not the same thing? And no, each cloud provider is going to structure things differently which is one of the reasons why multicloud stuff is so hard and tooling to support that can only run at the pace of the slowest cloud provider.

Comment: I am not looking to combine them (GCP and vSphere) together. For now, the requirement is to create separate provisioning via vSphere taking the GCP one as reference.

Comment: Ofcourse at a later stage, it will be a requirement to combine both providers.

Comment: This will be very hard. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791218/2291321 might be worth a read for why this is going to be difficult for you.