# Terraform choosing between different providers based on condition

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to use Terraform to automate the deployment of an environment, but there's something tricky with the setup:

I need to provision a DNS CNAME record, but my problem is that, based on the environment, I would need to provision that record either in [Dyn DNS](https://dyn.com/dns/) or Azure DNS (and they're mutually exclusive)

And, for the same reason, it wouldn't make sense for me to, for example, initialize the Terraform `Dyn` provider when I want to provision in Azure.

What I thought would work is to include the two `providers`:

```
provider azurerm {
  version = "=1.44.0"

  client_id       = var.dns_provider_client_id
  client_secret   = var.dns_provider_client_secret
  subscription_id = var.dns_provider_subscription_id
  tenant_id       = var.dns_provider_tenant_id
}

provider dyn {
  version = "=1.2.0"

  customer_name = var.dyn_customer_name
  password      = var.dyn_password
  username      = var.dyn_username
}
```

And then, when running `tf plan`, I would set the variables related to the provider I'm not using to empty string, and then, when provisioning the record, with the help from [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15281#issuecomment-308275154), I thought I can provision resources conditionally:

```
resource azurerm_dns_cname_record dns_name {
  count = var.dyn_dns_zone.name == "" ? 1 : 0

  name                = "..."
  record              = "..."
  resource_group_name = "..."
  ttl                 = 60
  zone_name           = "..."
}

resource dyn_record dyn {
  count = var.dyn_dns_zone.name == "" ? 0 : 1

  zone  = "..."
  name  = "..."
  value = "..."
  type  = "..."
  ttl   = 60
}
```

But my problem is that no matter what record I'm creating I need to initialize both providers, so even though I wouldn't need the `Dyn` provider for an environment, with the existing logic, I would still need to pass correct values (and not empty strings) to its required variables.

Is there any way to get around this? Maybe something along the lines of "only using a provider if I actually need it"

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791218/2291321 answer your question?

Comment: I don't think so, my issue is with, as I call it, *dynamic provider initialization*: I need to find a way (if there's any) to initialize a provider that I want to actually use to create a resource

Comment: Then there isn't a way to do this natively in Terraform because you can't do conditional providers directly. You'd need to either structure your code differently or you'd need to script something that does that for you. I'd go with the structure approach to keep it simple but it's not clear from your question if that would be enough for you.

Comment: Thank you @ydaetskcoR, you're right; I don't think there's an *easy* way to do this, and I'm thinking to do the DNS stuff separately so that I can `cd` to the correct provider folder structure and use it, instead of trying to do it dynamically

Comment: I am facing the same problem. What alternative approach did you follow to accomplish what you were trying to do, @Farzad?

Comment: Hey @javier, sorry for the late reply. It's been quite a while and if I remember correctly, I didn't manage to do this at the time. And again, if my brain isn't failing me, I think I ended up creating separate scripts to take care of this, since it was impossible (at least from what I gathered) to do it directly in Terraform

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have both providers initialized even if you don't provision resources for them based on logic.

Your dyn dns or Azure resource that is not the lucky one that will be provisioned because it has a count of zero should not show up in plan and the only values that should be evaluated on them would be those in the boolean expression you use to set the count.