# Movement from AWS to GCP with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have fully operational project in AWS created with Terraform. Now our client would like to move to GCP - is there any way of converting terraform scripts from AWS to GCP?

Comment: Nope. There isn't a direct 1:1 relationship with AWS and GCP so this is impossible. You'll need to work out what the equivalents are for everything and move things bit by bit. If this is a large project it's not going to be simple.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - Post your commend as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not. There isn't a direct 1:1 relationship with AWS and GCP so this is impossible. You'll need to work out what the equivalents are for everything and move things bit by bit. If this is a large project it's not going to be simple.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42791218/2291321) goes into a bit of detail about using Terraform in a cloud agnostic way if you needed to support multiple cloud providers at the same time but it's generally not considered best practice.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is looking for a solution, while this is not a complete solution but step 1 made easy:
To import your existing AWS Infra into terraform, we developed a tool on top of terraformer https://www.kapstan.io/generate-terraform. Try it out and give us feedback.
Once terramform is generated, you can will need to make a few edits before deploying on other cloud providers.