# Converting terraform google iac to terraform aws iac

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, terraform, migration

Any idea how to go about converting terraform google resources to their terraform aws equivalents? I’ve got a terraform google project but I’m needing to use the iac in aws. Insight appreciated.

The question is focused enough for people who know about IaC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me refer you to this question which is the other way around: from AWS to GCP: [Movement from AWS to GCP with terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829790/movement-from-aws-to-gcp-with-terraform)

Unfortunately there is no automatic conversion. Just think of the differences in detailed configurations let alone differences on a resource or concept level. So as the answer in the link mentioned: "You'll need to work out what the equivalents are for everything and move things bit by bit" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60936052/7337539)